# PHP zip does not work

Tags: php, drupal

I made a drupal module, one of function of the module is to compress some files to be a zip package. It works fine in my local environment(xampp), but fails on server. My server does has php zip extension enabled, since I can see zip information on php info and I can unzip file with php as well.

Besides, I already chmod files to be 0777 .

My code:

```
$folder = file_directory_path();

$zip = new ZipArchive();

if ($zip->open('b.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === TRUE) {

    foreach ( $files as $file ) {
        drupal_set_message(t($file)); // I can see the the message on this stpe
        $zip->addFile($file);
    }

    $zip->close();
    if (file_exists('b.zip')) {

        copy('b.zip', $folder . '/b.zip');
        unlink('b.zip');
        global $base_url;
        variable_set('zippath', $base_url . $folder . '/b.zip');
        drupal_set_message(t('new zip package has been created'));
    }
} else {
    drupal_set_message(t('new zip package failed'));
}
```

Comment: What error message occurs when it fails?

Comment: @Vulcan no error messages at all,thx

Comment: What version of PHP and XAMPP are you using ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes .. i know what you mean  .. this are the 3 possibility

- You have write permissions
- You Did not use full path
- You are including folders as file

You can try this

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "On");


$fullPath = __DIR__ ; // <-------- Full Path to directory
$fileZip = __DIR__ . "/b.zip";  // <---  Full path to zip

if(!is_writable($fullPath))
{
    trigger_error("You can't Write here");
}

$files = scandir($fullPath); // <--- Just to emulate your files
touch($fileZip); // <----------------- Try Creating the file temopary 


$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open($fileZip, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === TRUE) {

    foreach ( $files as $file ) {
        if ($file == "." || $file == "..")
            continue;
        $fileFull = $fullPath . "/$file";
        if (is_file($fileFull)) { // <-------------- Make Sure its a file
            $zip->addFile($fileFull, $file);
        }

        // Play your ball
    }
    $zip->close();
} else {
    echo "Failed";
}
```

Comment: thank you !it is file path to zip problem,but I don't know why it works on local environment(xampp) but didn't worked on server without full path to zip.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use rar or zip command to make zip. I am using linux and doing in my php system as

```
$folder = 'your_folder';  // folder contains files to be archived
$zipFileName  = 'Your_file_name'; // zip file name
$command = 'rar a -r ' . $zipFileName . ' ' . $folder . '/';
exec($command);
```

Its very quick. but you need to install rar package in your system.

Thanks